# Android: Youtube video in app. Youtube API Vs.Webview

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-webview

I have a view in my app that I need to display youtube videos. The design document has a scrollable page with a few youtube videos, one on top of another. I need it so that each video player, plays the one video set to it and the resets so that it can be played again. It can't suggest more videos and must be able to replay the same video.

I read somewhere that the youtube API has a limit on the number of plays that can come from a certain app before you have to start paying a fee. This is a concern for my app as it hopefully will hit that limit.

So my question is, for this scenario, which method of playing videos should I select? Will I be able to achieve this with just a webview?

I would be happy to provide more info as needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Webwiew and player API will be restricted with same quota, but that's nothing that you should be scared off. Quota is more like spams, not for your use case.